# How can I check if image is loaded using PHP?

Tags: php, python, asp.net, server-side

**Question:**

Consider the following code:

```
<img src="//www.externalSite.com/thisGraph.gif" alt="My image" />
```

Is there a good way to check with PHP if the above image loads successfully for the user?

**Some extra information:**

1. I cannot use Javascript (disabled clientside).
2. Py or ASP could be viable options if PHP falls short.

**Considerations:**

I do not know PHP well enough to think of methods that could be favorable here. But I'm thinking that if I load the image using PHP (or make it available to the user during page load), I could then somehow monitor the stream or load of that particular resource and take action depending on the result. If there are ways to do this server-side I will be more than happy if someone could point me in the right direction.

Maybe something similar to the following maybe:

```
return (!loadImage()) ? "image not loaded" : "image loaded";
```

Or could I maybe do a check if the client declined or blocked the image like so:

```
if(sendImageToClient() === 'accepted'){
    sendRestOfPage();
}
```

Comment: you cant check if something happens at client-side using a server-side technology. it will eventually have to be done using JavaScript. you could submit the results to the server-side script using http request after.

Comment: if clientside javascript is disabled, then there is nothing you could do because once the page leaves the server, there is no way for you to know if it has arrived safely unless the client reports back that everything is alright.

Comment: So there is no possible way to maybe send of some content to the client (say half the page) until the image is loaded, then report back about the image, and then perform some action depending on the feedback?

Comment: Parial page rendering can be achieved using ajax, but then again, you need javascript. Think about it like communicating using pigeons, how can you know if your pigeon has reached its destonation unless the destination sends another one back to inform you?

Comment: I understand your point, but this relates more to what the client is requesting, and how to respond to that request before the information is sent of to the client. The solution I have tinkered with is basically using an invisible iframe as landing: if no content inside the iframe was requested by the client (as in blocked), I can then use that information to redirect to the page I want the client to see. Any takes on that?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how the client is blocking the content. If the client does not request the content, you might be able to monitor that. However, if client uses a proxy of any sort that fully receives the page, and filters it before forwarding to the client, or if the content is being received by client but hidden from him by the browser, then the only way to check that would be at client-side using javascript.

Comment: Your question really is interesting, surely there is a workaround or a hack to achieve the desired behaviour, just need to dig deeper i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

instead of the image itself you could point to a php site that returns the image and save the download e.g. in a db.

However at that time the page is already at the client so you can't modify it anymore.